# Remove null properties in Sesam DTL

Tags: sesam

Using Sesam I'm left with a bunch of null properties.

How would i proceed to skip properties that are null completely in DTL?
Any examples of DTL that does this would be great.

Example

From:

```
{
  "address": "37484 Mohr Freeway\nNew Myrnaview, MI 89092",
  "birth_date": "2001-02-18",
  "column1": "01ba3bc2-8e22-4971-9683-b2ae05a39cd1",
  "column2": "null",
  "company": "Fay-Cole",
  "credit_card": "4049553515365",
  "first_name": "Dummy",
  "home_page": "http://www.mante.com/faq/",
  "job": "Airline pilot",
  "last_name": "User",
}
```

To:

```
{
  "address": "37484 Mohr Freeway\nNew Myrnaview, MI 89092",
  "birth_date": "2001-02-18",
  "column1": "01ba3bc2-8e22-4971-9683-b2ae05a39cd1",
  "company": "Fay-Cole",
  "credit_card": "4049553515365",
  "first_name": "Dummy",
  "home_page": "http://www.mante.com/faq/",
  "job": "Airline pilot",
  "last_name": "User",
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate. What is the goal you're trying to achieve? This makes it easier for people to help you with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can solved using a combination of the "key-values", "merge", and "apply" functions as shown here:

```
{
  "_id": "remove-null-values",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "embedded",
    "entities": [{
      "_id": "foo",
      "bar": "baz",
      "foo": null
    }]
  },
  "transform": {
    "type": "dtl",
    "rules": {
      "default": [
        ["merge",
          ["apply", "drop-nulls",
            ["key-values", "_S."]
          ]
        ]
      ],
      "drop-nulls": [
        ["filter",
          ["is-not-null", "_S.value"]
        ],
        ["merge",
          ["dict", "_S.key", "_S.value"]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The result will be:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "foo",
    "bar": "baz"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two different solutions:

Alternative 1:

```
{
  "_id": "test",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "embedded",
    "entities": [{
      "_id": "test",
      "a": 1,
      "b": null,
      "c": 2,
      "d": null
    }]
  },
  "transform": {
    "type": "dtl",
    "rules": {
      "default": [
        ["copy", "*"],
        ["remove",
            ["filter",
              ["is-null",
                ["path", "_.", "_T."]
              ],
              ["keys", "_T."]
            ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Alternative 2:

```
{
  "_id": "test",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "embedded",
    "entities": [{
      "_id": "test",
      "a": 1,
      "b": null,
      "c": 2,
      "d": null
    }]
  },
  "transform": {
    "type": "dtl",
    "rules": {
      "default": [
        ["copy", "*"],
        ["remove",
          ["map",
            ["first", "_."],
            ["filter",
              ["is-null",
                ["last", "_."]
              ],
              ["items", "_T."]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Alternative 3:

```
{
  "_id": "test",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "embedded",
    "entities": [{
      "_id": "test",
      "a": 1,
      "b": null,
      "c": 2,
      "d": null
    }]
  },
  "transform": {
    "type": "dtl",
    "rules": {
      "default": [
        ["copy", "*"],
        ["remove",
          ["map",
            ["nth", 0, "_."],
            ["filter",
              ["is-null",
                ["nth", 1, "_."]
              ],
              ["items", "_T."]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "test",
    "a": 1,
    "c": 2
  }
]
```